# is it possible to use inline if with react components?

Tags: reactjs

I recently learned about this. (what´s the name of it?)

```
condition && console.log("hello")
```

how can I use it with a component? like

```
condition && <MyComponent />
```

that´s it. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use inline for only true conditions:

```
{condition && <MyComponent />}
```

And for true and false conditions:

```
{condition ? <MyComponent /> : <MyFalseComponent />}
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use it on component like this,

```
{condition && <MyComponent />}
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render this line in *types*

> **Booleans** or **null**. Render nothing. (Mostly exists to support return test &&  pattern, where test is boolean.)